# A Post shared using Facebook Open Graph API doesn't appear on the timeline when shared user's profile is accessed from a friends profile

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Following OG tags are used when sharing a blog article from a iOS application.

og:type
og:title
og:description
og:url
fb:explicitly_shared
og:image

The app sets the "og:type" as "article" and "fb:explicitly_shared" tag  as "true". When the post is successfully shared from the application. It shows on the timeline of the person who shared it but, It's hidden from the friends of the person who shared it. The post is shared as public.
Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: Is the app used to share set to public yet, or is it still in developer mode?

Comment: @CBroe The app is live.

Comment: So the friend doesn’t see it when they go and view the posting user’s timeline?

Comment: @CBroe Correct. Same can be recreated by using "View as" option in the profile.

Comment: Hm, that rather sounds like the app was _not_ public ... Do you have example post URLs, and the app id?

Comment: @CBroe I resolved this issue by setting the "OpenGraphActionType" to "news.publishes" instead of "news.reads".